# $f:O \subset \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable application on $O$.Show that $f$ is constant when $O$ is an open connected set.

Tags: calculus, general-topology, derivatives, solution-verification, connectedness

I have a question inculding two questions. I would like to know if my answer, mostly the second one, is correct.

*Question:*
Let $ f:O \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ a differentiable application on a open set of $\mathbb{R}^m$. We suppose that $\vec{\triangledown }f= \vec{0} $ on all $ O $.
1/Prove that $f$ is constant on $O$ when $O$ is an open ball.
2/Prove that $f$ is constant when $O$ is an open conneceted set.

*My answer:*
1/By assummption we know that $ ||D \left \{ f(x) \right \} ||=|| \vec{ \triangledown } f || =  \vec{0} \Rightarrow ||f(\vec{a})-f(\vec{b})|| \leq 0 ||\vec{b}-\vec{a}|| = 0 $ for all $ x $ in any line segment $[\vec{a};\vec{b}] \subset O \Rightarrow \forall a,b \in O$ we have $f(\vec{a})=f(\vec{b})$ thus $f(\vec{x})$ is constant.
Q.E.D.
2/ As $O$ is a open connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ it is compact and thus it exists a finite cover of $O$ only by open balls. This means it exists a finite sequence $(B_i)_{1 \leq i \leq N}$ of open balls such that $ O \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{N}B_i $
Hence it cames that $\forall x \in O \Rightarrow \exists i_0 \; s.t. \; x \in B_{i0}$ and so $f$ is constant on $B_{i0}$.
now as $f$ is constant on all $B_i \cap  O$ and that $f$ is continuous on $O$ (by assumption as $f$ is differentiable on $O$ ). So $f$ is constant on $O$.
Q.E.D.

Is it correct? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you say an open connected set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact? What about $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself?

Comment: @Bcpicao thank you for your answer, you re right but I thought that the question only refer ro a subset of $\mathbb{R^m}$

Comment: I don't know if connex means connected, but the only open compact set on $\mathbb{R}^n$ Is the empty set as compact set are closed and bounded and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected. So there are no proper clopen subsets

Comment: @Marco Thk you for your time. Yes it means connected I am going to edit the message.

Comment: @X0-user-0X you didn't quite get my point, $\mathbb{R}^+$ is an open connected (strict) subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is not compact. Remember $S\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded. You should instead use the fact that an open connected set is path connected.

Comment: @Bcpicao you re right.  So how to prove it?

Comment: @Bcpicao if I try to improve my proof and i writte that any $O$ can de covered by a countable union of balls is my proof correct?

Comment: No, that can't work, since any set can be covered by a countable union of balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (since it is Lindelöf).

Comment: @Bcpicao , ok so anyone to help? :-)

Comment: up anyone to help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using my hint in the comment above, since an open connected set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is path connected, one can consider the function $f\circ\gamma: [0;1]\to \mathbb{R}^n$ with $f\circ\gamma(0)=a$ and $f\circ\gamma(1)=b$, for $a,b\in O$.

Thus: $$|f(b)-f(a)|\leq \max_{t\in[0;1]}[ \gamma’(t)\cdot \nabla f(\gamma(t))]\cdot|b-a|=0$$

which shows that $f$ is constant on $O$.

Comment: thank a lot I did not pay attention enough to it. Thk you.